# How to fix 'UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason' is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfielddelegate

I am getting this error

> 'UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason' is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer

for this code

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason) {
            if(reason == UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason.committed)
            {

            }
        }
```

I know that I can use below code

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    }
```

But my question is how I can use `UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason` with compatibility of iOS 9. I tried if #available(iOS 10, *) but it's seems that it can't work for  functions

Comment: if UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason not available in ios9 then you can't use it in ios 9,  You have fin some alternate way

Answer (score 1):

Its not used as `if #available(iOS 10, *)`. Its `@available(iOS 10.0, *)`

In your code replace:

```
  func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason) {
        if(reason == UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason.committed)
        {

        }
    }
```

with:

```
  @available(iOS 10.0, *)
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason) {
    if(reason == UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason.committed)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: And where is else part for lower iOS version ?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `@available`:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason) {
...
}
```

Documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html).

Comment: And where is else part for lower iOS version ?

Comment: there's no else part simply again write the same line for the version you require but lower version functions should be below the higher version functions.

Comment: so I have to write `func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)` for each lower version i.e 9, 8, 7, 6 .....